# Word document mergers using Apache POI generating ' file corrupt error' after merger

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx, netbeans-8

Hey guys note this appears to be a similar problem to a [previous post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFLwl.png) - but the solution posted there does not resolve my error.

My requirements were to,

1) load multiple word documents and 
2) merger the word documents into a single word document.

Guys some effort I was able to merge the files using the Apache POI API. However once I attempt to the open the merged file, Microsoft Word generates the following error,

*"Word found unreadable content in final.docx. Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of this document, click Yes."*

[image]

Guys note Microsoft Word is however able to fully recover the file, after I click 'YES'; the resultant files having been correctly merged. However I would like to eliminate the file corrupt error warning, if possible.

My code listing for the merger class,

```
package rx.reportgenerator.gh;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBody;
/**
 *
 * @author kwadwooteng-amoko
 */
public class WordMerge {



    private final OutputStream merger;
    private final List<InputStream> docs;
    private XWPFDocument first;



    public WordMerge(OutputStream result) {
        this.merger = merger;
        docs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(InputStream document) throws Exception{            
        docs.add(document);
        OPCPackage src = OPCPackage.open(document);
        XWPFDocument xDocument = new XWPFDocument(src);     
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = xDocument.createParagraph();
        paragraph.setPageBreak(true);
        if(docs.size() == 1){
            first = xDocument;
        } else {            
            CTBody xBody = xDocument.getDocument().getBody();
            first.getDocument().addNewBody().set(xBody);            
        }        
    }

    public void doMerge() throws Exception{
        first.write(merger);                
    }

    public void close() throws Exception{
        merger.flush();
        merger.close();
        for (InputStream input : inputs) {
            input.close();
        }
    }   

}
```

My library dependancies to the best of my knowledge, are all upto date:

[image]

No idea guys why the code is generating an error. Although the merger completed accurately. Can you help me guys

Comment: What your code does is appending multiple `body` elements to `/word/document.xml`. But merging `Word` `*.docx` files  is not as simple. The `body` elements may referencing different numbering in `/word/numbering.xml`, different styles in `/word/styles.xml`, different fonts in `/word/fontTable.xml`, ..., different media in `/word/media/` and so on. So the error results on a reference in one of the appended `body` elements which is not present in that `*.docx` file. That is because you do not merging the other document parts and do not updating  `/word/_rels/document.xml.rels`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What I am doing is merging a set of documents which are all based off the same template. The styles are the same, the number mechanism is the same and so are the fonts, all the same. Will that still impact the document

Comment: "Will that still impact the document ?": Well, it seems, since you got that error. As said simply appending multiple `body` elements to `/word/document.xml` is **not** merging `*.docx` files. `Word` itself does not appending multiple `body` elements to one `document`. In `Office Open XML` XML Schema of `CT_Document` the `body` element has `maxOccurs="1"` set. And what about different media, charts, ...? And how can you be sure nobody had added different numbering, font or else?

Comment: Thanks. Is there away around the problem then

Comment: Traversing all [IBodyElement](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/IBodyElement.html)s of source document and get needed settings of them. Then add those `IBodyElement`s to the target document's body as new elements and set the settings. A very complex and challenging task.

Comment: @KAlistair Were you able to come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this problem has already been solved. However, as I just faced the same issue with this error I would like to share my solution for others:

When generating empty table cells with apache poi in a word file, the same error occurs. For some reason, word does not like those empty cells. After I added .addParagraph() for all emtpy cells in my table, the error disappeared. Source: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65292